# Trying to understand the delayed job polling query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, haskell, delayed-job

I'm trying to port Delayed Job to Haskell and am unable to understand the `WHERE` clause in the query that DJ fires to poll the next job:

```
UPDATE "delayed_jobs"
SET locked_at = '2017-07-18 03:33:51.729884',
    locked_by = 'delayed_job.0 host:myhostname pid:21995'
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM "delayed_jobs"
  WHERE
  (
      (
        run_at <= '2017-07-18 03:33:51.729457'
        AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2017-07-17 23:33:51.729488')
        OR locked_by = 'delayed_job.0 host:myhostname pid:21995'
      )
      AND failed_at IS NULL
  ) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *
```

The structure of the `WHERE` clause is the following:

```
(run_at_condition AND locked_at_condition OR locked_by_condition) 
AND failed_at_condition
```

- Is there a set of inner parentheses missing in `run_at_condition AND locked_at_condition OR locked_by_condition`? In what precedence are the AND/OR clauses evaluated?
- What is the purpose of the `locked_by_condition` where it *seems* to be picking up jobs that have already been locked by the current DJ process?!

Comment: You're asking about SQL but you tagged your question with two irrelevant tags and not with SQL.

Comment: Let me know how the Haskell goes as well ;)

Comment: @ReinHenrichs thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 1):

The statement is probably fine. The context of the whole statement is to *take the lock* on the highest-priority job by setting its `locked_at`/`locked_by` fields.

The where condition is saying something like: "if `run_at` is sooner than now (it's due) AND, it's either not locked or it was locked more than four hours ago... *alternatively* that's all overridden if it was me that locked it, and of course, if it hasn't failed THEN lock it." So if I'm reading it correctly it looks kinda like it's running things that are ready to run but with a timeout so that things can't be locked-out forever.

To your second question, `AND` has a higher precedence than `OR`:

```
SELECT 'yes' WHERE false AND false OR true;   -- 'yes', 1 row
SELECT 'yes' WHERE (false AND false) OR true; -- 'yes', 1 row
SELECT 'yes' WHERE false AND (false OR true); -- 0 rows
```

The first two statements *mean* the same thing, the third one is different.

The second point may just be a rough sort of ownership system? If the current process is the one that locked something, it should be able to override that lock.